# Installation failed INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED

Tags: android, android-manifest

Installation failed with message INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED. It is possible that this issue is resolved by uninstalling an existing version of the apk if it is present, and then re-installing.  WARNING: Uninstalling will remove the application data!  Do you want to uninstall the existing application? please help me

Answer (score 2):

Try to check these :

1. Activity name should be prefixed with "." in your manifest file
2. Check if you don't have a taskAffinity attribute without dot :

   android:taskAffinity=".string"
3. Your package name use only lowercase
4. This error can be cause by a lot of different mistake in your manifest.xml file. Check this file carrefuly...

Comment: everything must be check sir but don't no what are problem facing right now

Comment: 1. remove cache file from ur phone and android studio contain invalidate file remove...my suggestion is every time running your app clean and rerun.